# Регистронезависимые url в медиабиблиотеке WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Имею на руках backup сайта на WordPress. После миграции его на хостинг все работает, но несколько картинок не грузятся. Сначала я подумал, что дело в https в пути, но нет. Оказалось, что в имени картинки и адресе есть разница в заглавной букве, стоит ее поменять в девтулзах и картинка появляется. На локальном сервере такого эффекта нет, там картинка отображается вне зависимости от регистра в адресе. Например:
ссылка на файл: [https://azaza.com/Картинка](https://azaza.com/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) - не отображается.
[https://azaza.com/картинка](https://azaza.com/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) - отображается.

Вопрос, как так получилось, что в самой ссылке адрес изменился на другую букву не стоит (возможно ее туда по ошибке поставили), более интересно, как заставить хостинг не показывать картинки, будто регистр не имеет значения.

P.S. Если в .htaccess заменить буквы на маленькие, проблема не решится, суть в том, что нужно обратиться к файлу, будто он в Windows, т.е. не важно, какой регистр. В папке Windows не может быть "Папка" и "папка", поэтому я могу создать "ПАПКА" и обратиться к ней "пАпкА" и я в нее попаду.

Как реализовать?

Comment: [Ошибка XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy/710#710). Тебе нужно правильно залить картинки. Для начала сравни в регистр в бекапе. А возможно, что и [бекап нужно сделать правильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562).

Comment: Картинок было несколько штук, поправил руками. Это было самое простое решение и нужно было чтобы все срочно заработало. Сам бэкап попал в руки именно в таком виде, переделать невозможно.
Вопрос в самом принципе, как убирается регистрозависимость?

Comment: @SudoTrololo Никак. Это свойство операционной системы.

Comment: @SudoTrololo Если в бекапе регистр не правильный, это значит что бекап сделан неправильно. А значит есть большая вероятность что регистр - меньшее из бед. Настоятельно рекомендую сделать миграцию правильно. Ссылка выше.

Comment: Миграцию заново сделать невозможно.
Если никак, понял, спасибо.